# Chrome opens to untitled blank page

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome

I am working on a computer that had a lot of malware on it. I removed most of it to my knowledge. Now when I open Google Chrome I get a blank untitled page, with the traditional sign-in URL on top.  If I go to the settings, the settings tab opens up blank as well. All pages that I navigate to will come up blank as well. The browser doesn't even perform a postback, it is like it is unresponsive. I did some googling and have seen people with similar errors, but no fixes.

IE 8 works great without issues.

Re-installing Chrome was the first thing I did!

Any suggestions?

Comment: you seriously haven't tried reinstalling chrome?

Comment: You can try and delete the Chrome's current profile.  We need more information in order to help you.

Comment: seriously re installing chrome was the first thing i did!

Comment: @Ramhound Do you know where that is located in the folder?

Comment: on Windows 7 its `C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\Application\Default`. You can create a new profile folder by appending this `–user-data-dir=”d:\<new chrome user directory location>”` to your chrome shortcut property. [Source](http://www.howinthetech.com/relocating-google-chromes-user-profile-directory/)

Comment: selecting the 'exit' option on the bottom of the settings list and re opening chrome fixed it for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This was not my computer but one i was fixing for a friend. The issue was the it was running in Compatibility mode for windows XP service pack 2. After re installs it set it self back to that i am assuming because i did not set it to that. Thanks for the help .

Answer (score 2):

Check out the compatibility mode in the shortcut's properties.

Mine was checked with Windows XP SP2.

Unchecked it, now Chrome works perfect!

Seems stupid, but it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem with Chrome & as I was performing the solution here I discovered a different problem. "Run this program as an administrator" box was checked in the Compatibility tab. After clearing the box & applying it Chrome went right back to work as usual. Yeah!